# How to run a launchd task every weekend once?

Tags: macos, cron, ruby, launchd

I am trying to run a ruby program as a cron. I have figured out how to run the ruby program from a launchd The problem is that I don't know how to say "Run the job once every Sunday". Below is my .plist file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>EnableGlobbing</key>
    <false/>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>ScratchFolders.job</string>
    <key>ProcessType</key>
    <string>Background</string>
    <key>Program</key>
    <string>/usr/local/rvm/wrappers/scratch-monitor/ruby</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string></string>
        <string>scratch-clean.rb</string>
    </array>
    <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
    <string>/tmp/ScratchFolders.job.err</string>
    <key>StandardOutPath</key>
    <string>/tmp/ScratchFolders.job.out</string>
    <key>StartCalendarInterval</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>Weekday</key>
            <integer>7</integer>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>WorkingDirectory</key>
    <string>~/automation-scripts/</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Answer (score 1):

The first and biggest problem is that you are using the `Program` and `ProgramArguments` keys wrong. They're rather confusing because they correspond to the first two arguments to `execvp`, and unless you understand `execvp`, you won't understand these keys properly. But there's a simple way to do it in most cases: don't use `Program`, and put the full path to the program in the first string in `ProgramArguments`:

```
<key>ProgramArguments</key>
<array>
    <string>/usr/local/rvm/wrappers/scratch-monitor/ruby</string>
    <string></string>
    <string>scratch-clean.rb</string>
</array>
```

(Note: I'm assuming you're trying to pass a blank first argument to the program -- if not, remove the `<string></string>`.)

The second problem I see is the `WorkingDirectory` key -- I'm pretty sure it won't expand `~` in this context, so you need to specify the full path explicitly:

```
<key>WorkingDirectory</key>
<string>/Users/chan/automation-scripts/</string>
```

Finally, I think you may also need to specify the hour and minute to start it at:

```
<key>StartCalendarInterval</key>
<dict>
    <key>Weekday</key>
    <integer>7</integer>
    <key>Hour</key>
    <integer>3</integer>
    <key>Minute</key>
    <integer>15</integer>
</dict>
```